# Can I get a lowercase-L character with Computer Modern which doesn't look like 1?

Tags: fonts, computer-modern

I'm writing a document using one of the default document class (i.e. no changes to the default fonts). I want my `$\text{lpos}$` not to look so much like `$1\text{pos}$` ... can I somehow get an l which is either a bit rounded, or perhaps, say, a top serif to the left and a bottom serif to the right (but not in italic font)? Or anything that doesn't look like a 1, really. I can't use `$\ell$`, that's too much unlike the rest of the text.

by the way, it looks like this question is relevant not just to Computer Modern:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: this is going to be a consideration with just about every serif font in modern use.  the tugboat article "[Oh, oh, zero!](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-2/tb107bigelow-zero.pdf)" by chuck bigelow touches on it to some degree, and you might be able to find some useful examples there.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `\textrtaill` symbol from the `tipa` package. It's longer than a lower-case `l` so it has to be resized with `\resizebox*`.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tipa,graphics}

\newcommand{\el}{\raisebox{\depth}{\resizebox*{\width}{\height}{\textrtaill}}}

\begin{document}

1pos lpos \el pos
\end{document}
```